# TFS2017 Update 1 NPM Feed Upstream sources - 'tfs' is not in the npm registry

Tags: npm

I have an on-premise TFS 2017 Upgade 1 and setup the NPM Feed with **Upstreams sources**.

I can publish packages to TFS NPM feed.

I get the following error when trying to install a package which should come from **upstreams** source.

```
C:\Users\yser\Source\Repos\BPI>npm install lodash
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "lodash"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 NotFound The package 'lodash' was not found in feed with ID '23093b
d8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32': tfs
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'tfs' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohammadreza.yaesubi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-
06-19T20_53_12_708Z-debug.log
```

Here is the log dump of connecting to NPM Feed:

```
15 http request GET http ://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_packaging/NPM-Test/npm/registry/lodash
16 http 404 http ://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_packaging/NPM-Test/npm/registry/lodash
17 verbose headers { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
17 verbose headers   pragma: 'no-cache',
17 verbose headers   'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
17 verbose headers   expires: '-1',
17 verbose headers   server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
17 verbose headers   'x-tfs-processid': '25b2b015-fef5-4d2a-b370-facfc02df495',
17 verbose headers   'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
17 verbose headers   'x-vss-userdata': '76c0cbe2-e5a8-4f2a-8dbd-e3bc7cbd57b3:user1',
17 verbose headers   activityid: 'fbf7a055-58b7-4df9-9761-43b159a56b4c',
17 verbose headers   'x-tfs-session': 'fbf7a055-58b7-4df9-9761-43b159a56b4c',
17 verbose headers   'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
17 verbose headers   'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
17 verbose headers   p3p: 'CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"',
17 verbose headers   'lfs-authenticate': 'NTLM',
17 verbose headers   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
17 verbose headers   date: 'Wed, 21 Jun 2017 17:31:40 GMT',
17 verbose headers   'content-length': '139' }
18 verbose stack Error: NotFound The package 'lodash' was not found in feed with ID '23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32': tfs
18 verbose stack     at makeError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:308:12)
18 verbose stack     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:296:14)
18 verbose stack     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:216:14)
18 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
18 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
18 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
18 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
18 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
18 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
19 verbose statusCode 404
20 verbose pkgid tfs
```

Here is the log from TFS App-Tier Event :

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 6/26/2017 2:29:29 PM
Machine: TFSApp_tier
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-1-131404998408365697
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319
Service Host: 
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 7712
  Thread Id: 6400
  Account name: S-1-5-21-2129867641-1448237841-168566570-1243740

Detailed Message: The package 'lodash' was not found in feed with ID '23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32'

Web Request Details
    Url: http://TFSApp_tier:8080/tfs/_packaging/NPM-Test/npm/registry/lodash [method: GET]
    User Agent: npm/4.2.0 node/v7.10.0 win32 x64
    Headers: not available
    Path: /tfs/_packaging/NPM-Test/npm/registry/lodash
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: <omitted>
    User: domain\TFSSERVICE [authentication type: Federation]

Exception Message: The package 'lodash' was not found in feed with ID '23093bd8-41aa-403d-9d3f-5c713b14ce32' (type PackageNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Npm.Server.Registry.NpmUpstreamRegistryService.<GetUpstreamRegistrationJsonAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Npm.Server.Registry.NpmUpstreamRegistryService.<GetRegistrationJsonAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Npm.Server.Registry.NpmRegistryService.<GetRegistrationJsonAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Npm.Server.Controllers.NpmRegistryController.<GetPackageAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Npm.Server.Controllers.NpmRegistryController.<GetPackageAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mamrez

Comment: Can you successfully install other packages? Make sure you set the credential correctly with .npmrc file in your client machine to run the install command. You can use command "npm view [package name] dist.tarball" to check if the package "lodash" exists in the registry. the command will return the URL of the compressed package file if it exists 
 there.You can also try to restart the machine, after restarting then try the steps in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc

Comment: Also, please make sure you have enabled the npmjs.org as an upstream source for the feed you created.

Comment: I tried the 'npm view [package name] lodash' or any other package name and still the same error. I've already enabled the upstream source in the feed (i.e. enabling checkbox). laptop has been restarted as well. my settings are also correct;followed the 'npmrc' setup multiple times step by step. I can publish local npm packages to feed, but any install/view that needs 'npmjs.org' upstream source fails with the same error. I've updated the question with log dump for further investigation

Comment: So, you can not return the URL of  "lodash" package by running the command "npm view lodash dist.tarball"? Can you install the packages directly from npmjs.org (you can try this from another client or delete/change the registry in .npmrc file), if the TFS can not connect to npmjs.org , it will not get the packages.

Comment: I get the same error. I checked the TFS App-Tier and enabling the internet access, still facing the same issue. Updated the question with TFS App-Tier event viewer dump. hope that helps.

Comment: All the log message return PackageNotFoundException, cannot find the package, you need to check the npmjs.org connectivity first, just try to run the "npm install lodash" command manually in local command line to check if that works. If that works, you can try to clean the caches in both Application Tier and Client server, then create a new Upstreams sources feed to try it again.

Comment: Still no luck on this issue. same error. I can run 'npm view lodash dist.tarball' from TFS App-Tier which goes to npmjs.org. In the developer machine running same command, fails complaining that 'tfs' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: This might look outdated, but I still have the issue!. one of the comments was "ensure if the TFS can not connect to npmjs.org , it will not get the packages." The TFS App-Tier has proxy in npm config to access the npmjs.org. I've also been able to install a package in TFS app Tier for connectivity testing. Is there any other setting required to ensure TFS has connection to npmjs.org? Thanks